# Shiny App error with valid N/A, App says columns not found. How can It be fixed

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server

How do I get shinny app to stop producing an error due to the valid N/A in certain columns? The N/A are valid and I would like to display them as absent in my Shiny app, But I first need to get past the error that certain columns show no data at all. They do not have any info but the absence of data is needed to showcase just that 'absence'.

The error I keep getting states that the column or columns can not be found bc there is no data in the column ( which is true)

Here is a snippet of the df in question

```
structure(list(Id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), HR_DATE = c(2022484408, 
2022484408, 2022484408, 2022484408, 2022484408, 2022484408), 
    Dates = c("4/12/2016", "4/13/2016", "4/14/2016", "4/15/2016", 
    "4/16/2016", "4/17/2016"), TotalSteps = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), SedentaryMinutes = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Calories = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), TotalMinutesAsleep = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WeightPounds = c("NA,NA", 
    "NA,NA", "NA,NA", "NA,NA", "NA,NA", "NA,NA")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))





#Shiny app

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("input_1", "Select ID:", choices = c(1503960366,1844505072,1927972279,2022484408,2026352035,2347167796,4020332650,4057192912,4388161847,4558609924,
                                                   4702921684,5553957443,5577150313,6117666160,6290855005,6775888955,6962181067,7007744171,7086361926,8253242879,
                                                   8583815059,8792009665,8792009665)),
  radioGroupButtons("input_2", "Select Columns:", choices = c(TotalSteps,SedentaryMinutes,Calories,
                                                              TotalMinutesAsleep,WeightPounds),
                    selected = 0,
                    status = "default",
                    size = "normal",
                    direction = "horizontal",
                    justified = FALSE,
                    individual = FALSE,
                    checkIcon = list(),
                    width = NULL,
                    choiceNames = NULL,
                    choiceValues = NULL,
                    disabled = FALSE),
  sliderInput("input_3", "Select a date:", min = as.Date("2016-01-01"), max = as.Date("2016-12-31"),
              format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
  plotOutput("output")
)
                           
                           
 server <- function(input, output) {
  # Reactive expression for the selected ID from the selectInput() function.
  selected_id <- reactive({
    input$input_1
  })
  
  # Reactive expression for the selected date from the sliderInput() function.
  selected_date <- reactive({
    as.Date(input$input_3, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
  })
  
  # Reactive expression for the data for the scatter plot, filtered by the selected ID, column, and date.
  data <- reactive({
    # Get the data for all IDs, columns, and dates.
    data <- data.frame(
      id = seq(1503960366, 8792009665, by = 1),
      column = c(TotalSteps, SedentaryMinutes, Calories, TotalMinutesAsleep, WeightPounds),
      date = seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"), by = "day", length.out = 365),
      value = rnorm(365 * 25)
    )
    
    # Filter the data to the selected ID, column, and date.
    data <- data[data$id == selected_id() & data$column == selected_column() & data$date == selected_date()]
    
    # Return the data.
    data
  })
  
  # Render the scatter plot with the data from the
}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: `selected_column()` appears to be undefined in your code.  Also, I believe you are confusing *selection* (the choice of a subset of columns) with *filtering* (the selection of rows)...

Comment: @Limey  If you are refreing to the "Select Columns" this is only a name title in the shiny app ( the display name for the actual Button.  My issue  I dont belive is in the shiny app but in how the df is recognizing the  N/A I believe. I may be wrong. I am not sure.